# Extracting POST params with Express.js 3

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just getting started with node and express.js and I'm having some trouble dealing with a POST request. I'm posting info that will be written to an activity log. The request looks like this:

```
POST /activities/log HTTP/1.1

san=3252080&event=MY_EVENT
```

My server (the relevant part):

```
var app    = express();
var routes = require( './routes' )( app );

app
  .use( express.bodyParser() )
  .listen( port );
```

My route:

```
activities.log = function( req, res, next ) {
  console.log( req.body.san );
};
```

The result (minus stack trace):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'san' of undefined
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple & fundamental, but my code seems consistent with what I've seen in my searches so far. There are similar questions on SO, but none that match my scenario or give an answer that works for me.

Comment: have you tried `req.params`?

Comment: I have/did. It's an empty array. I know that's telling in some way, but I'm not sure what to make of it. It's the `req.body` that's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app    = express();
app.use( express.bodyParser() )

require( './routes' )( app );
app.listen( port );
```

Comment: Thanks, @chx007. This works, but would you mind adding a little context for it? I'd like to understand how Express.js works to understand what makes the order of operations so critical in this particular case. Either way, I appreciate the nudge forward.

Comment: It is because you need to set up all the middleware before defining a route, so, the route was processed without the bodyParser middleware who enables the req.body object.